# How to find in and out time of every employee

Tags: sql-server

Given Table:

```
id       time_stamp                  Access Type    
0301    2013-09-05 09:35:00         IN
0302    2013-09-05 11:00:00         IN
0301    2013-09-05 12:00:00         OUT
0302    2013-09-05 12:25:00          OUT
0301    2013-09-05 13:00:00          IN
0302    2013-09-05 14:00:00         IN
0301    2013-09-05 17:00:00          OUT
0302    2013-09-05 18:00:00         OUT
```

Expected Output:

```
id      first_in    last_out    date           duration(last_out - first_in)
0301    09:35       17:35       2013-09-05          08:00
0302    11:00       18:00       2013-09-05          07:00
```

I need a efficient SQL query for prepared statement in java.

Comment: yeah me too :D. how abt u share what u've done so far....

Comment: Where does Java really come in here? Surely any SQL you can come up with could be used from any platform. Have you *tried* any SQL yet? How far have you got?

Comment: Well, if you need an SQL query, you should start writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `id` and `cast(time_stamp as date)` to create one row per person per day:

```
select  *
,       datediff(minute, first_in, last_out) as duration
from    (
        select  id
        ,       min(case when [Access Type] = 'IN' then time_stamp end) as first_in
        ,       max(case when [Access Type] = 'OUT' then time_stamp end) as last_out
        ,       cast(min(time_stamp) as date) as date
        from    Table1
        group by
                id
        ,       cast(time_stamp as date)
        ) as SubQueriesMustBeNamed
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a51d79/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query that joins the table to itself with various criteria to filter `In` and `Out`.

**Build sample data:**

```
-- temp table for your sample data
CREATE TABLE #GivenTable
    (
      [id] INT ,
      [time_stamp] DATETIME ,
      [Access Type] VARCHAR(3)
    );
-- insert your sample data        
INSERT  INTO #GivenTable
        ( [id], [time_stamp], [Access Type] )
VALUES  ( 0301, '2013-09-05 09:35:00', 'IN' ),
        ( 0302, '2013-09-05 11:00:00', 'IN' ),
        ( 0301, '2013-09-05 12:00:00', 'OUT' ),
        ( 0302, '2013-09-05 12:25:00', 'OUT' ),
        ( 0301, '2013-09-05 13:00:00', 'IN' ),
        ( 0302, '2013-09-05 14:00:00', 'IN' ),
        ( 0301, '2013-09-05 17:00:00', 'OUT' ),
        ( 0302, '2013-09-05 18:00:00', 'OUT' );
```

**SELECT Query:**

```
SELECT  tIn.id ,
        MIN(tIn.time_stamp) AS FirstIn ,
        MAX(tOut.time_stamp) AS LastOut ,
        CONVERT(DATE, tOut.time_stamp) AS AccessDate ,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                 MIN(tIn.time_stamp), 
                 MAX(tOut.time_stamp)) / 60.0 AS DurationInHours
FROM    #GivenTable tIn
    INNER JOIN #GivenTable tOut ON tOut.id = tIn.id
               AND CONVERT(DATE, tOut.time_stamp) = CONVERT(DATE, tIn.time_stamp)
WHERE   tIn.[Access Type] = 'IN'
        AND tOut.[Access Type] = 'OUT'
GROUP BY tIn.id ,
        CONVERT(DATE, tOut.time_stamp)
-- clean up temp table
DROP TABLE #GivenTable
```

The `FROM` clause here joins to the same table twice on `id` and the date portion of the `time_stamp`.

The `WHERE` clause specifies `tIn.[Access Type] = 'IN' AND tOut.[Access Type] = 'OUT'`. This means the data in `tIn` is the `IN` data and `tOut` is the `OUT` data.

`MIN` and `MAX` are used to get the `FirstIn` and `LastOut` values, and `DATEDIFF` is used to calculate the time difference.

The `GROUP BY` uses `CONVERT(DATE, tOut.time_stamp)` to take off the time portion of the datetime, so that records for the same day can be grouped together.

This assumes people will never work across day boundaries / be working night shifts.

Comment: Why the self-join? A `case` inside the `max()` can distinguish between in and out records and is much simpler

Comment: @Andomar didn't really consider that when I started writing, but agree it's probably simpler.

Comment: how the query will look like,if people works across day boundaries / be working night shifts.

Comment: @GauravRajput that's a completely different question in my opinion as the answer will have to be very different. For a start you would need a way of identifying which events (ins and outs) are during a single shift, other wise you have no way of grouping the records as 1 shift. It doesn't look like you have that information, so I couldn't possibly answer that.